# Support for cordova-plugin-camera 7.0 api 33 Android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I was using @awesome-cordova-plugins/camera in my capacitor 5 project but with new Android API 33 camera stopped working.
As far as i know the problem is solved with cordova-plugin-camera 7.0.

I tried implementing cordova-plugin-camera 7.0 directly but it gives me an error like this:
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cordova-plugin-camera'

My import is:
import "cordova-plugin-camera"

Is there any plan to solve the issue with awesome-cordova-plugin too?
Or i am using cordova-plugin-camera in the wrong way?

Edit: obviously i runned npm install with the correct version of cordova-plugin-camera and i checked node-modules to be sure the file was there

Thanks

Comment: Please consider using Capacitor camera: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/camera

Comment: If you are using Cap5, then use the Cap camera plugin instead.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the project was a port from Cordova. Converting the plugin from Cordova to Capacitor would require a significant refactoring that I would prefer to avoid. If I can't find a solution in the near term, then I would be forced to go down that path.

Comment: @RiccardoBenedetti: Did you find any solution for the same. Even for our project we cant go for capacitor.

Comment: @Vanu at the end we decided to replace the plugin with the capacitor version